# Showing "Sorry, Something went wrong" message while try to login facebook through react native application

Tags: react-native, facebook, react-native-fbsdk

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above, I got the warning message when I added "user_friends" to loginButton.setPermissions("email", "public_profile", "user_friends"), but when I tried logging into Facebook, I received a message saying, "Sorry, something went wrong." Is this a permission disable issue or not?

It has been over a year since I submitted the app and there were no issues. However, it is one month before the issue begins.

React native package used is : react-native-fbsdk-next

[image]